# Trying to understand the implications of passing an object to a function

Tags: javascript

This is my function:

```
function myFunction(theObject) {
    theObject.make = 'Saab';
} 
var mycar = {
    make : "volvo";
    model :1992;
};
```

Doing something like `this:console.log( myFunction(myCar));`
    shouldn't it print out `volvo` rather than `undefined`?

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You aren't returning anything from `myFunction`, which just implicitly returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the return value of function `myFunction`.

`myFunction` has no return value. So you are printing `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

From your code posted in the question:

- You need to "declare" properties using comma instead of semicolon (otherwise you get error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`).
- A function without a return statement will return `undefined`.

> When a return statement is called in a function, the execution of this
>   function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the
>   function caller. If the expression is omitted, undefined is returned
>   instead.
>   Source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Here below an example of your code adding `return` and fixing issue with semicolon.

In the example you can notice:

- We pass an object mycar to myFunction.
- myFunction change property of object from 'volvo' to 'Saab';
- The result in alert() will be the object's property modified, 'Saab'.

```js
function myFunction(theObject) {
  return theObject.make = 'Saab';
}
var mycar = {
  make: "volvo", // use comma instead of semicolon
  model: 1992
};

// doing something like this:
alert(myFunction(mycar));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to return 'Volvo' you have to use `return`, that means that your function should return something, otherwise it will return `undefined` because it didn't find anything to return.

```
function myFunction(theObject) 
{{ theObject.make = 'Saab'; } 
 var mycar = {make : "volvo"; model :1992;};
 return mycar;
}
```

P.S. You are missing a '{ }' at the begin and the end of your function.

Comment: When using your code the browser will return error VM75:45 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; for this line var mycar = {make : "volvo"; model :1992;}; try to edit it using comma instead of semicolon when creating property for object mycar.